# How to insert the values of radio button into db from form

Tags: forms, angular, radio-button

I am trying to insert the radio button values to db but how can I do that?

```
<form id="login-form" name="login-form" class="nobottommargin" [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)">
<p *ngIf="activation" class="activation">We sent you an activation link to your email</p>
<input type="radio"  [formControl]="form.controls['type']"  name="optradio">Personal

    <input type="radio"  [formControl]="form.controls['type']" name="optradio">Professional

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" [formControl]="form.controls['firstname']"  placeholder="First Name" class="form-control not-dark formcontrolheight" required>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" [formControl]="form.controls['lastname']" id="login-form-password" name="login-form-password" value="" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control not-dark formcontrolheight" required>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 topmargin-sm bottommargin-lg nopadding text-right pull-right">
                        <button type="button" class="button button-small">submit</button>
        </div>

export class SignUp {
    http: Http;
    emailfailure:any;
    activation:any;
    profilefailure:any;
    form: ControlGroup;

    constructor(fbld: FormBuilder, http: Http, public router: Router) {
        this.http = http;
        this.form = fbld.group({
        firstname: ['', Validators.required],
            lastname: ['', Validators.required],
            profilename: ['', Validators.required],
            email: ['', Validators.required],
            password: ['', Validators.required],
            repeatpassword: ['', Validators.required],
            image: [''],
            phone: ['', phoneValidator],
            type: ['', ],
    }, { validator: matchingPasswords('password', 'repeatpassword') });

}
```

Comment: can you provide your component's code or better to create a jsfiddle with this and better explain the problem (or error)?

Comment: Oleg Barinov,pls see it nw

Comment: You've mentioned 'db', but I see no communications with http service or whatever and which exception have you got...